# PHP mail() function not functioning

Tags: php, email

This is my first time using the PHP mail() function, and I am just trying to send out a very basic email to start with.

I have a WAMP server installed on my computer, which I use for testing purposes. This is the code I'm using.

```
$to = "me@gmail.com";
$subject = "Test mail";
$message = "Just testing.";
$from = "Your mom.";
$headers = "From:" . $from;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

As far as I can tell, the entire PHP file executes without error, however I'm not receiving any emails. Perhaps I haven't configured something I should, or my syntax is incorrect. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Look in your spam folder? Its possible that the source of the email being unsure gmail or hotmail or whatever is treating your emails as spam.

Comment: In fact, you need of SMTP service/Daemon. THe PHP script is OK

Comment: It's not a spam folder issue, and I've read that it should work with gmail, even if it doesn't have a proper source.

Comment: @felipsmartins - Could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

For sending email through php script  **mail()** function is used.

But emails will be sent only when smtp server has been configured into **php.ini** file (Configuration file for php).

Both configuration parameters  for SMTP server must  be set in php.ini file.

(1) **SMTP**
(2) **smtp_port**

Please refer the below mentioned url for sending email from localhost
http://blog.techwheels.net/send-email-from-localhost-wamp-server-using-sendmail/

Comment: SMTP is set to localhost and SMTP_Port is set to 25.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem - it wasn't giving me any issues, but it wasn't sending the email either. I wrote a blog on it, but here's the important line to include:

```
ini_set("sendmail_from", $email_from);
```

Here's the full coding for the email that worked:

```
$to = $email;
$message = "HEre's the message";
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Website<contact@myemail.com>' . "\r\n";
$subject = "Hello World!";
$body = $message;
$email_from = "contact@myemail.com";
ini_set("sendmail_from", $email_from);
mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
```

If you want to read the whole blog explaining it, here's a link: http://kimjoyfox.com/blog/use-php-to-send-an-email/

Answer (score 0):

`mail` is evil because it almost never tells you when it's actually failed.

Use [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) or [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/) to connect to sendmail or an SMTP server directly, which will at least give you a clue when something has gone wrong sending mail.

Answer (score 0):

I have just tried your code on my gmail. Email received. Therefore, in my opinion server is not configured to sent email (check requirements on http://www.php.net)

Answer (score -1):

Add this to php.ini if already you have this then modify it as below..

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
SMTP = localhost
smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
;sendmail_from = Sachinmodi9@gmail.com // u can try yours..
```

Add this inside your php script at top..

ini_set("SMTP","aspmx.l.google.com");

and run the script..

if it shows success message then check it out your inbox.. if mail is not there then check your SPAM box too..